# Dynamic nested form controls Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder, angular-forms

my API response is like

```
"groups": [{
          "group_name": "GRP1"
          "attributes": [{
                        "attribute_id": 1,
                        "attribute_name": "Frequency",
                        "value_reference": "tag"
                        }]
          },
          {
            "group_name": "GRP2"
           "attributes": [{
                        "attribute_id": 2,
                       "attribute_name": "Date",
                        "value_reference": "static",
                        "value_static_type": "date"
                      }]
              }]
```

-- How I can create formConrol in Angular 4 to display data like

```
GroupName  
   List of Group's Attribute  
GroupName
    List of Group's Attribute
```

My initial form control is like

```
this.editTemplateForm = this.fb.group({
            groups: this.fb.group({
                group_name: ['', Validators.required ],
                attributes : this.fb.group({
                    value_reference : []
                })
            }),
        });
```

I don't understand how add control dynamically

Answer (score 2):

The structure here ends up being fairly complicated, if you'd like to match your API response exactly. Since, so far, each `attributes` property only has a single object of attributes, you could potentially make `attributes` an Object directly, instead of an array of objects, which would simplify the following code. The code below matches your current API structure, and can be played with at [this working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hpuPdh?p=preview).

Some things to keep in mind:

- `FormGroup` needs to be the outer-most form object, and can also be used to hold an indeterminate number of `FormControl` items
- `FormArray`, on the other hand, is useful when the number of controls is indeterminate, **and** it does not matter what those controls are called.
- this is why, below, `allGroups` is an array holding the largest groups, and `attributes` is an array holding your attribute objects, but those attribute objects themselves are groups - because we want to be able to name the controls based on their API property name

There's also a good chance this structure isn't *exactly* what you're looking for (e.g. perhaps you didn't want all these values to be editable `<input>` fields), but it should give you a strong basis to play with on the plunker, and understand how you can dynamically generate HTML based on changing form objects.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray, FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';

interface APIGroup {
    'group_name': string;
    'attributes': Array<GroupAttributes>
}
interface GroupAttributes {
    'attribute_id': number;
    'attribute_name': string;
    'value_reference': string;
    'value_static_type'?: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h3>I'm the Child component</h3>
    </div>
    <form [formGroup]="editTemplateForm">
        <div formArrayName="allGroups">
            <div *ngFor="let group of editTemplateForm.get('allGroups').controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
                <input formControlName="groupName" />
                <div formArrayName="attributes">
                    <div *ngFor="let attributeGroup of group.get('attributes').controls; let n=index" [formGroupName]="n">
                        <input *ngFor="let key of keysOfFormGroup(attributeGroup)" [formControlName]="key" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <pre style="background: #ddd">{{editTemplateForm.value | json}}</pre>
  `,
})
export class ChildComponent {
    constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder
    ) { }

    sampleData: Array<APIGroup> = [
        {
            "group_name": "GRP1",
            "attributes": [{
                "attribute_id": 1,
                "attribute_name": "Frequency",
                "value_reference": "tag"
            }]
        },
        {
            "group_name": "GRP2",
            "attributes": [{
                "attribute_id": 2,
                "attribute_name": "Date",
                "value_reference": "static",
                "value_static_type": "date"
            }]
        }
    ]

    editTemplateForm: FormGroup;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.editTemplateForm = this.fb.group({
            allGroups: this.fb.array([])
        });

        // would call on a subscription to actual api data
        this.sampleData.forEach(group => {
            (<FormArray>this.editTemplateForm.get('allGroups'))
                .push(this.initGroup(group));            
        });
    }

    initGroup(apiGroup: APIGroup): FormGroup {
        let formGroup = this.fb.group({
            groupName: [apiGroup.group_name],
            attributes: this.fb.array([])
        });
        apiGroup.attributes.forEach(attributeGroup => {
            (<FormArray>formGroup.get('attributes'))
                .push(this.initAttributeGroup(attributeGroup));
        });
        return formGroup;
    }

    initAttributeGroup(attributes: GroupAttributes): FormGroup {
        let formGroup = this.fb.group({});
        Object.keys(attributes).forEach(name => {
            formGroup.addControl(name, new FormControl(attributes[name]));
        });
        return formGroup;
    }

    keysOfFormGroup(group: FormGroup): Array<string> {
        return Object.keys(group.controls);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @JackKoppa for your reply. Your answer definitely give me some idea to go ahead with my API response. I also found another useful Plunker link - https://plnkr.co/edit/hpuPdh?p=preview . Thanks again

Comment: sorry, above link is yours. What I found is - http://plnkr.co/edit/3k23R3z2KHlAXW5OLKRA?p=preview

Comment: Nice, that plunk also looks very applicable. If this answer is sufficient, please feel free to mark it as accepted, and let me know if you have any other questions

Comment: Hey @JackKoppa do you know how I can add new form group control to "attributes" ? On button click I need to add Group and new Attribute row. I manage to add new group but dont know how to add in Attribute

Comment: Should be as simple as `formArray.push()`, passing in the new `FormGroup`. Let me try updating the plunk with that type of button

Comment: Yes and I tried this code - https://www.screencast.com/t/T2FxBdJY. but its not push valid control.

Comment: From the code you linked there, it should be just about as simple as removing your two `.controls` properties. You don't modify that directly, and you can actually use `.push()` directly on the formArray.

I've updated the [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/hpuPdh) (definitely feel free to fork it & play around), and you can use the "Add Attribute Group" buttons to add a random group from the additional sample data I added. `addAttributeGroup()` is the new method most equivalent to what you linked above.

Comment: Hi, your plunker is broken, could you update your fix?